# Как сделать, что бы при уменьшении экрана div'ы не разъезжались?

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

Что то я не могу понять в чем дело? Почему так происходит? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться! Вся вёрстка на Bootstrap у меня.

При полном размере экрана div'ы в таком виде, картинка и под ней белая плашка с текстом, мне так это и надо.

При уменьшении экрана, div'ы адаптируются и уменьшаются, всё как и положено.

Но стоит дойти до разрешения экрана, где не помещаются два div'а, и они начинают выстраиваться один под одним (это тоже нормально). Но происходит следующее, что картинка встаёт в нужное положение, а div с белой плашкой на которой текст смещается влево:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это исправить? Вот код секции (за написания кода не судите строго, только учусь):

HTML код:

```
<section id="latest-works">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Check out our latest works</h2>
                <p class="large">Magnis modipsae que voloratati andigen 
                 daepeditem quiate re porem aut labor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center cont">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="item-works">
                    <img src="img/work1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="works">
                        <h4>Grand Motel gets an identity brushup</h4>
                        <p>Identity</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="item-works">
                    <img src="img/work2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="works">                 
                        <h4>Grand Motel gets an identity brushup</h4>
                        <p>Identity</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS код:

```
body{
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; /*font-family: 'Lato', sans-
    serif;*/
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #73879c;
    font-weight: 400;
    }

img{
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

h1{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 78px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
}

h2{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #506a85;
  font-weight: 700; 
}

h3{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #506a85;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h4{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #506a85;
  font-weight: 700;
}
/* ============================latest-works============================== */
#latest-works{
  padding: 80px 0;
  background: #f2f5f7;
}

#latest-works .works{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.works p{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #73879c;
}

.cont{
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Ссылку на сайт скиньте

Comment: Так как я только учусь, лендинг который верстаю, находиться локально на компьютере.

Comment: А как Вы его верстали, если Вы код не знаете?

Comment: Как не знаю, знаю! Но код на компе локально, как мне его вам показать? Или вам будет достаточно кусочка кода этой секции которая у меня не получается?

Comment: Покажите хотяб кусочек кода, и CSS код этого кусочка

Comment: Прочитайте про [mcve]

Comment: В коде, который вы предоставили, невозможно понять в чем проблема, т.к. нет ни изображений, ни css с медиа-запросами.

Comment: Поэтому я изначально не выкладывал код, вот скажите как мне загрузить и показать вам код так что бы он работал так как у меня? Куда мне изображения поместить, которые в коде использованы? И ещё тут нет подключенного бутстрапа, а он нужен для полноты картины. Но я выложил код того места где у меня проблема. И описал и указал картинкой суть проблемы

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой "фрагмент кода" и добавляйте код туда. А сторонние библиотеки подключайте ссылками по аналогии с js, которые доступны в системе

Answer (score 1):

В каждом row сумма col-xx-x должна быть 12. У Вас в первом row  col-lg-8, должно быть col-lg-12

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-12'>
    <!-- Ваш код -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-6'>
    <!-- Ваш код -->
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-6'>
    <!-- Ваш код -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'>
    <!-- Ваш код -->
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-4'>
    <!-- Ваш код -->
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-5'>
    <!-- Ваш код -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)
- хороший ресурс для обучения и не только

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы текст был по центру, то проще изначально вставить его в контейнер с:

```
display: flex; 
justify-content: center;
```

И тогда как бы вы не меняли ширину браузера\экрана, он всегда останется по центру ширины.

Или же можно сделать блок 100% ширины с фиксированной какой вам нужно высотой, стиль которого будет

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
```

так вы расположите текст по центру блока.